# How To Create Method Extend from CrudRepository for Composite Key

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have 1 class ContainerLoadList with Composite Key ContainerLoadListPK like this

```
@Embeddable
public class ContainerLoadListPK implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3526479259987259367L;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 13)
    @Column(name = "ContainerNo")
    private String containerNo;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 6)
    @Column(name = "VesselCode")
    private String vesselCode;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 8)
    @Column(name = "Voyage")
    private String voyage;

    public ContainerLoadListPK() {
    }

    public ContainerLoadListPK(String containerNo, String vesselCode, String voyage) {
        this.containerNo = containerNo;
        this.vesselCode = vesselCode;
        this.voyage = voyage;
    }

    public String getContainerNo() {
        return containerNo;
    }

    public void setContainerNo(String containerNo) {
        this.containerNo = containerNo;
    }

    public String getVesselCode() {
        return vesselCode;
    }

    public void setVesselCode(String vesselCode) {
        this.vesselCode = vesselCode;
    }

    public String getVoyage() {
        return voyage;
    }

    public void setVoyage(String voyage) {
        this.voyage = voyage;
    }
}
```

and I have another interface extended from CrudRepository like this

```
public interface ContainerLoadListRepository extends CrudRepository<ContainerLoadList, ContainerLoadListPK> {
    List<ContainerLoadList> findByBNo(@Param("bNo") String bNo);

    @Query(name = "ContainerLoadList.findByVesselCodeAndVoyage")
    List<ContainerLoadList> findByVesselCodeAndVoyage(@Param("vesselCode") String vesselCode,@Param("voyage") String voyage);
}
```

Are You Have Another Solution for findByVesselCodeAndVoyage without using @Query?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the embedded key field inside `ContainerLoadList` is called `pk`, you can try this:

```java
List<ContainerLoadList> findByPkVesselCodeAndPkVoyage(String vesselCode, String voyage);
```

For more information, check the [Spring Data JPA Property Expressions documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-property-expressions).